# Resetting radio button selector JQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Next button, when clicked, should load the new question, load the answer choices, and reset the form. The reset is not working:using latest JQuery, Chrome. CSS and HTML are pretty straightforward and the rest of the code works.

```
$("#nextQuestion").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault;
        i = i + 1;
        console.log(i);
        $("#questionText").text(questions[i].question);
        $("#choice1").text(questions[i].choices[0]);
        $("#choice2").text(questions[i].choices[1]);
        $("#choice3").text(questions[i].choices[2]);
        $("#choice4").text(questions[i].choices[3]);
        $(".questionnumber").text("Question " + currentQuestionNumber + " of five.");
        $("input:radio").prop('checked', false);

    });
```

Any ideas why the reset isn't working.

Comment: any error in your console

Comment: No. I tried a bunch of different ways too. But no error.

Comment: what is the value of `currentQuestionNumber`... I think it should be `i`

Comment: Try debugger in your browser console. You will find error.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5mdohf19/1/ - if you have defined the variable `currentQuestionNumber` it looks fine

Comment: else  http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5mdohf19/2/ - you will have an error like `Uncaught ReferenceError: currentQuestionNumber is not defined` in your console

Comment: No error. currentQuestionNumber isn't the issue. Its that the form does not reset. Teh radio button stays checked.